# Mouse and keyboard take long time to activate when disks are connected

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, keyboard, mouse

When booting up Windows 7, my mouse and keyboard (USB) take a small while before they are operational, depending on the number of external hard disk drives connected to the PC during boot (also USB).

For example, if I have no external disks on, the mouse and keyboard are operational immediately. If I have one disk on, they may take 2-3 seconds to activate. If I have two, they take about double this time, and so on.

The problem is that the system in question has a large array of disks, both internal and external (7 external disks to be exact, 4 of them through a hub) and if they are all connected during boot, the mouse and keyboard will take about 20-30 seconds to activate.

If these disks are connected after Windows has booted, there is no problem with the mouse and the keyboard, but it's inconvenient to do that every time. The OS is installed on a solid state drive (but the behavior and the times were the same when the OS was on a mechanical hard disk drive).

What is the reason for this and (more importantly) are there any convenient (software-based, preferably) workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they're all sharing the same USB bus, the 7 external have to be spun-up and checked first, in case one of them holds system data.

So the USB device polling probably stops until all 7 of those drives are checked.

Ensure the devices (specifically the mouse/Kb vs. the drives) are a on separate USB "hubs" (not a physical hub, but the internal "hubs" listed in the Device Manager), or perhaps add an additional/separate USB controller ([example](http://ca.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Cards/4-Port-PCI-Express-USB-3-Controller-Card~PEXUSB3S2E2I)) and connect either the drives or the mouse/KB to it.